# Do I need to root my Android mobile to run my own applications?

Tags: android

If I write an application using the Android SDK or NDK, can I simply copy the APK produced onto any Android phone (with the right version of the OS running) and run it?  Or do I need to root the phone before apps not bought through a marketplace can run?

The context is that I have the choice of a Galaxy S2 as an upgrade to my iPhone4 and I'd like to start writing my own stuff.  I can find plenty of instructions and examples of compiling and running apps *in the emulator*, but nowhere explicitly states I can run the apps I compile on the S2.  I'm worried that apps may need to be signed or authenticated before they can run on it (and other phones) and I'd rather not mess about with the phone too much.

Comment: No you do not have to, you can download SDK, connect your phone via USB and run and test your applications on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's hard to be sure about this without actually having access to the hardware.

Comment: if you're in apprehension about rooting, just do it!
its fun for one and you'll realize how much more can you do with your phone if you root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download it and run it without root.

You can debug directly on a device even from your development environment.

Android development tools environment (ADT) in eclipse (as well as others) and the correct ADB USB drivers for your phone gives you that nice option. Much faster than using the android emulator too.

In settings you have to  allow debug (a simple checkbox), that is all.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to root. Just install drivers and SDK. Using eclipse you can directly run on device and debug too

it's also faster than working on emulator

Answer (score 2):

If you get Galaxy S2, then you can install Samsung's own free app, "Kies Air". This allows you to transfer files over wifi from your PC to anywhere that you can see in the phone's file explorer. If you transfer an apk this way, then when you click on it in the phone's file explorer, it will install the app. The app can be signed with a debug key, or a release key.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need root. In order to instal on android phones you simply install the app on the phone through eclipse ADT tool or just through the ADT terminal. Just remember to set the phone to development mode by going into settings -> programs, then allow installing from unknown sources.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you want to install the *.apk on you device download an app from market. Follow this link for guides on both this approach and the SDK/debug approach: http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/install-apk-files-on-android/